# Что такое lazy и eager операторы?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

При изучении Stream API, часто встречал употребление выражений lazy и eager операторы, но нигде толком не мог найти нормальное определение этих понятий.

Может кто нибудь доходчиво объяснить?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation или https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-util-stream/lazy-evaluation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В программировании термины:

- *Lazy evaluation* означает, что вычисления производятся только тогда когда нужен их результат.
- *Eager evaluation* - означает, что вычисления производятся строго по запросу.

Например, допустим вы сортируете массив `int arr[]`- операция достаточно затратная в вычислительном смысле.

Традиционно принято выбирать подход *eager*, вызываем сортировку массива: `Arrays.sort(arr)`, далее пользуемся результатом.

В случае *lazy* - массив заранее не сортируем, а сортируем только в момент когда нам понадобится `arr[i]` - некий элемент сортированного массива - и только тогда вызываем сортировку - чувствуете разницу?

В Stream API почти все операции *lazy*, промежуточные вычисления производятся только при вызове терминальных операций типа `reduce()/count()/collect()` и т.д.

Comment: Ну наконец то, нормальное объяснение, спасибо:)